# How to use 'Authorization Bearer' in headers and response?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

**Check this below service code.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DataJson } from "../models/dataJson";
import { AppSettings } from '../app.settings';

@Injectable()
export class StepsServices {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}    

    postGetPanelists(params, token): Observable<DataJson[]> {
        debugger;
        let tokenHeaders = new Headers({
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+token,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        });

let tokenOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: tokenHeaders });

  return this.http.post(AppSettings.BASE_API_URL+'demo/demo/', params, tokenOptions)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) {
  let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
}
```

**Like this I am calling service**

```
  panelists
  getPanelistsAPI(){
    let params = 'id=AB-12-BC';
    let token = atob(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    this.stepsServices.postGetPanelists(params, token).subscribe(data =>{
      this.panelists= data[0];
    });
  }
```

**this is response data in network**

Here we are not seeing parameters and other details.

> General: Request
>   URL:http://localhost:9090/demo/demo
>   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Request headers: Provisional headers are shown
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
>   Access-Control-Request-Method:POST Origin:http://localhost:4200
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167
>   Safari/537.36

Comment: Please check this code anything wrong with it.

Comment: you are using old version of angular ..better to upgrade it.!

Comment: Can you post in more detail what response are you getting? For example what's the response status code?

Comment: @rijin ok is there any solution for this

Comment: @curlyBraces What I mentioned in question that is:

General: Request URL:http://localhost:9090/demo/demo Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request headers: Provisional headers are shown Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization Access-Control-Request-Method:POST Origin:http://localhost:4200 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36

this much only i can see